# Where am I making the mistake?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I was trying to find the range of $x^2 + 2xy + 3y^2 - 6x - 2y$.

So, i made it equal to $S$ and solved for y to get its roots and optimize the expression for real values.

Clearly, the expression inside the square root (which is the discriminant), should be more than or equal to $0$ for real values of y. The discriminant, here, is $-8x^2 + 64x + 12S + 3$.

So, if y has to be real, $-8x^2 + 64x + 12S + 3$ has to more than or equal to $0$.

But note that the expression here is a downward opening parabola, which cannot be more or equal to $0$ for all real values. Then this implies that there does not exist any value of x and y such that $x^2 + 2xy + y^2 - 6x - 2y$ holds real values. But this is contradictory, as there are many values for which the expression reaches real values. Then where am I making the mistake?

NOTE: I'm asking y'all to point out my mistake only. I'm not asking for solutions to this question. I've been able to solve this but I'm not able to explain the contradictory situations that are arising here.

Comment: What is $S$?${}{}$

Comment: Sorry xD I've edited it now.

Comment: You want $-8(x-4)^2+12S+132$ to be non negative for some value of $x$. Clearly this has maximum when $x=4$ and then $S\ge -11$ is needed to ensure non-negativity. Hence you get the lower range.

Answer (score 1):

$$E=x^2 + 2xy + 3y^2 - 6x - 2y = (x+y)^2+2y^2-6x-2y$$

Put $z = x+y$ and express $x=z-y$. So we get
$$E= z^2+2y^2-6z+6y-2y = z^2+2y^2-6z+4y = 2(y+1)^2-2+(z-3)^2-9$$

So $E_{\min} = -11$ and $E$ does not have maximum.

Comment: This is how I would have solved the problem too, but it does not really answer OPs question about where his/her mistake is.

Comment: In your first line, $E = x^2 + 2xy + 3y^2 - 6x - 2y = (x + y)^2 + \color{red}{2}y^2 - 6x - 2y$.

Comment: Firstly you've made a simplification mistake. The answers gonna be -11. My method righteously leads to this. But I'm just skeptical about the fact that the expression is the equation of a downward parabola and can never be more than or equal to 0 for ALL real values of x and S, i.e. Can someone point out my mistake? It's been a hell lotta time since I've been digging this from evening.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try this?
let $$f(x,y)=x^2+2xy+3y^2-6x-2y$$ then we get
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=2x+2y-6$$
and
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=2x+6y-2$$
and solve the System
$$2x+2y-6=0$$
$$2x+6y-2=0$$

Comment: No no no! I'm just asking y'all to point out my mistake.

Comment: Ah there it is again, can kindly point me to somewhere that explains why this works? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let $$x^2+2xy+3y^2-6x-2y=k$$

$$\iff x^2+2x(y-3)+3y^2-2y-k=0$$

As $x$ is real, the discriminant must be $\ge0$

i.e.,  $$(y-3)^2-(3y^2-2y-k)\ge0$$

$$\iff k\ge2y^2+4y-9=2(y+1)^2-2-9\ge-11$$

Comment: stupid question : isn't it supposed to be b^2 - 4ac ie (y-3)^2 - 4*(3y^2 - 2y - k)?

Comment: @Vrisk,  What is $b$ here?

Comment: Oh i see, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, -8x^2 + 64x + 12S + 3 doesn't need to be more than or equal to 0 for ALL real x, y, s. In x^2 + 2xy + 3y^2 - 6x - 2y = S, consider S to hold any PARTICULAR value >= -11. Then think about this: if the discriminant has to be more than or equal to 0 for all real x's, it would mean that the parent expression must also be defined for all real x, which is certainly not true for any given value of S. 
-8x^2 + 64x + 12S + 3 (subject to S >= -11) is more than 0 for selected values of x and not all real x.

Thank you everybody for whatever efforts they had imparted to this question.